# calling a command in for loop every 1 minute

Tags: java, linux, shell, unix, sleep

I am running my runnable jar file like this:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -jar data_test.jar config.properties > test_jar_100.txt
```

Now I want to run the above command in a for loop 100 times but it should sleep for 1 minute before calling it again and file name should get incremented by 1 in every run.

So flow should be like this:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -jar data_test.jar config.properties > test_jar_100.txt
sleep for 1 minute
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -jar data_test.jar config.properties > test_jar_101.txt
sleep for 1 minute
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -jar data_test.jar config.properties > test_jar_102.txt
.. keep doing this 100 time
```

So I got below for loop but not sure how do I sleep for 1 minute before calling it again and increment the file count by 1 with every run?

```
for ((i=1;i<=100;i++)); do /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -jar data_test.jar config.properties > test_jar_100.txt; done
```

Comment: Can you call `sleep 60`?

Comment: @EricRenouf `60`?  Or do you mean `60 * 1000`? Myself, I'd consider using a ScheduledExecutorService.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels if it's at a bash prompt it's in seconds, so `60`

Comment: There is a startup cost to invoking the JRE; do you really need to structure your program this way?

Comment: `sleep 1m` will also work fine which I figured it out but I am more confuse for incrementing the file count by 1 with every run.

Comment: @david `echo 1+1|bc`

Comment: `for ((i=100; i<200; i++)); do whatever > test_jar_$i.txt; sleep 1m; done` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `sleep` command to pause the execution of your loop for a minute and for the file name, adding "$i" variable to the name should be enough:

```
for ((i=1;i<=100;i++)); do 
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -jar data_test.jar config.properties > "test_jar_${i}.txt"
    # Sleep for a minute 
    sleep 60  
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming a common Linux environment with bash, you could execute:

```
for i in $(seq 100 199) ; do echo "iteration $i" ; /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -jar data_test.jar config.properties > test_jar_$i.txt ; sleep 60 ; done
```

Answer (score 3):

Why are you counting your loop from 1 if you are numbering your files from 100?

`for ((i=100; i<200; i++)); do yourlongcommand > test_jar_$i.txt; sleep 1m; done`